# Get month grouped in django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset

As of now I have tried extracting month details using

```
total_dict = MyModel.objects.values('Gender', 'DOJ').annotate(count=Count('Gender')).order_by('DOJ', 'Months')
for d in total_dict:
    d['DOJ'] = str(d['DOJ'].month)
print total_dict
```

the output is:

```
[{'DOJ': '1', 'Gender': u'Male', 'value': 1}, {'DOJ': '1', 'Gender': u'Male', 'value': 1}, {'DOJ': '1', 'Gender': u'Female', 'value': 1}]
```

What I want is to add the values of entries with the same gender together, e.g. instead of `{'DOJ': '1', 'Gender': u'Male', 'value': 1}, {'DOJ': '1', 'Gender': u'Male', 'value': 1}` there should be a single entry `{'DOJ': '1', 'Gender': u'Male', 'value': 2}`

My model.py is

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
Dept=models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True, default=None)
Gender =models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True, default=None)
Shift =models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True, default=None)
Months=models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True, default=None)
DOJ=models.DateField(null=True)
```

Months field is not actually needed!

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data for your model schema?

Comment: @Anomitra i have shared my models! please check

Comment: So basically, you want the _sum of values_ for every DOJ-Gender pair?

Comment: @Anomitra yes correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
total_dict = MyModel.objects.annotate(month=TruncMonth('DOJ')).values('Gender', 'month').annotate(sum=Count('Gender'))
```

Try this.

Comment: i want male count separately and female count separately of each month

Comment: @cloud Updated.

Comment: @cloud I have updated my answer, tested this query on my system and it works fine. Does it work for you? If not, can you do `print total_dict` and show the output?

Comment: Thankyou very much!:)

Answer (score 0):

```
total_dict = MyModel.objects.values('Gender', 'DOJ').annotate(Count('Gender')).order_by('DOJ', 'Months')
for each_dict in total_dict:
    each_dict['value']=each_dict[0].Gender__count
print total_dict
```

refer [aggregation in django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/)

Comment: KeyError: 0 for each_dict[0].Gender__count